# Store different types of variables

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, 2d

I am trying to find a solution to my problem. I see something in Game Maker called `ds_grid` which is something like a dynamic 2D array, but every single field can contain different types of variables.

You can get the values by indexes e.g. `ds_grid_get(mygrid,row,column)`. I need something similar, but can't find anything, that can work which can hold different types, can't be dynamic, and vice-versa.

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: What language? Please at that as a tag.

Comment: Sorry, I mean C++.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

"similiar, but sligtly different" ofter means that there is a common base class (or you should create one). You can create a container of base class pointers which can hold any of the derived types. If there is no common base class, you can use [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html) to store different types in one container.

```
 // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/variant.hpp"

int main()
{
  std::vector<boost::variant< int, std::string > > w = {"as", 12};
  std::cout << w[0] <<std::endl;
  std::cout << w[1] <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Okay, i try to understand this, i never do anything like this before :)